Error in Jenkins build using msbuild when no error in Visual Studio
I am new to Jenkins and msbuild (Visual Studio Build Tools 2022 is installed!) and am getting an error when I build from Jenkins, which I do not get when I build the solution in Visual Studio.  The error is:
C:\JenkinsHome\workspace\Foo\FooWithToken\Source\CommonPlatform\UnitTests\DatabaseInterfaceTests\AnalysisSettingsMigrationTest.cs(12,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'VisualStudio' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) . 

Strangely, I am not getting this error when I build with Visual Studio.  I don't believe the library in question is a NuGet package but that said, I have a nuget restore line which I share below.  When I look at Visual Studio, and the project references for the project that AnalysisSettingsMigrationTest.cs is in, I see that it has as one reference:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll 

And this file IS there!
What could be going wrong?  Why am I seeing this error with Jenkins?

Here is the pipeline script:
    pipeline {
    agent { label 'WindowsFoo' }//any
    tools {
        msbuild 'MSBuild 2022'  // I don't believe this is used
    }

    stages {
        stage ('Clean workspace') {
              steps {
                // Clean before build
                cleanWs()  
                // cleanWs fails if ANY console window is open or windows explorer is open to workspace
                
              }
            }
            
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {

                        script 
                        {                       
                             bat 'git lfs --version'
                             echo 'call checkout'
                              checkout scmGit(branches: [[name: '*/master']], extensions: [lfs(), checkoutOption(120)], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'FooGIT_ID', url: 'https://github.com/Foo/Foo-software.git']])    
                             
                        }
                   
            }
        }

        
        stage('Restore packages') {
              steps {
                bat "dotnet restore ${workspace}\\Source\\FooFilter.slnf"
                
              }
        }
        
        stage('Print Environment') {
    steps {
        echo 'show PATH'
        bat 'echo %PATH%'
        echo 'show MSBUILDPATH'
        bat 'echo %MSBuildPath%'
        // Add other relevant environment variables
    }
}

        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                
               echo 'build'
               
               dir("C:/JenkinsHome/workspace/Foo/FooWithToken/Source")
               {
                   script {
                    echo 'inside build part'
                    
                   bat '\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\MSBuild\\Current\\Bin\\msbuild\" FooFilter.slnf /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=\"x64\"'
                  
                }
               }
               
               
               
            }
        }

        
        
    }

    
}


Looks like your reference is to a direct path on your computer, therefore it is not found on the build machine, you will have to add it as a relative reference, or better add it as a nugget package so it will be rederived during the NuGet restore phase.
